# Does NS-3 supports Mobile IPv6?

Tags: networking, mobile, ns-3

I have to simulate a few scenarios of network mobility (MIPv6). I was told to use NS-3, but I don't find any good information about it. Can anyone give me some lights about this? I just need to simulate a few simple scenarios of networks moving around...
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are two ways to do ns-3 MIPv6 simulations:

- using DCE: http://www.nsnam.org/~thehajime/ns-3-dce-umip/getting-started.html
- using a native UMIP implementation from http://eudl.eu/pdf/10.4108/ICST.SIMUTOOLS2010.8682 but I do not believe that it has been released.